# I want to update an array using a hook, but I always get an error

Tags: reactjs

I tried to update my array with a new value, but I got the below error every time.
Here's my code so far

```
const [pdfs, setPdfs] = React.useState([]);
const newArray = [];

const getPdf = (id) => {
   newArray.push(id);
   console.log(newArray);

   setPdfs((prevState) => ({
    pdfs: [...prevState.pdfs, id],
   }));

}
```

Here is the error that is thrown

> prevState.pdfs is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const [pdfs, setPdfs] = React.useState([]);` you passed empty array as initial value to `pdfs`, so prevState is `[]` and there is no `prevState.pdfs` to iterate on. if you want to have object with pdfs key you should change the first line to

`const [pdfs, setPdfs] = React.useState({pdfs:[]});`

Answer (score -1):

You are returning an object, return array:

```
const [pdfs, setPdfs] = React.useState([]);
const newArray = [];

const getPdf = (id) => {
   newArray.push(id);
   console.log(newArray);

   setPdfs((prevState) => (
    [...prevState.pdfs, id],
   ));

}
```